# How to automate BlackBerry debugging with Eclipse?

Tags: scripting, blackberry, build-automation, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am developing application for BlackBerry 8900 and I am using features that force me to test/debug it on the real device. I am looking for a convenient way to be able to automate build-deploy-lanuch process.

The process is:

1. Package application & sign it
2. Load it on the device
3. Start debugging session in Eclipse

With the newest version of BlackBerry plugin for Eclipse, step 1. is almost painless, but I would like to get rid of dialogs that I am missing some debug files. Step 2. and step 3. must be performed manually. Ideally I would like to turn it all into one script, Eclipse macro, whatever....

Has anyone tried something like this with any success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For automating some process, such package, sign and run you can use [BB-Ant-Tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/).

Also, for load on device you can use [javaloader.exe](http://www.blackberry.com/DevMediaLibrary/view.do?name=javafinal).

Some links: [this](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/138210-setup-up-eclipse-blackberry-development-print.html) and about debugging on device [this](http://na.blackberry.com/developers/resources/A50_How_to_Debug_and_Optimize_V2.pdf).